# infopath form not updating fields

Tags: 2013, infopath, lookup-column, form

I have an infopath form that has three read-only fields referencing items in another list, but when someone opens the form the values never change, even if they have changed in the other list. It looks like they just keep whatever the original value was. How do I make them "refresh" every time someone views the form?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you referencing other fields?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: As in, are they calculated fields, lookup fields, etc

Comment: The are the default values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this right, the reason the fields are not updating is because they are set as default values, which are only assigned once. What you want is a data connection to the other list that can pull the values you want, and then when a user opens the form it will have the updated values in it.

Check out [this](http://manojssharepointblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/create-infopath-form-with-lookup-functionality-to-sharepoint-list/) article to see how to do it.

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/introduction-to-rules-HA010381865.aspx) is an article about setting rules. The difference in your case is you'll be setting a form load rule, which is in a slightly different spot. In the ribbon go to the Data tab and you'll see an option for form load rules.

Comment: So does this only work for choice fields, or anything?

Comment: Ah sorry forgot the other half of that. See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

In the window **Edit Defaul Values** only uncheck the option "**Refresh value when formula is recalculated**"